# Google PubSub throttling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a chain of data pipelines communicating to each other through pipeline-specific Pub/Sub topics.

```
[pipeline #1] -> [pipeline #2] -> [pipeline #3] -> ...
```

Each pipeline is totally stateless and can scale horizontally based on the respective pub/sub queue size.

Each pipeline has its own throughput.
The `pipeline #2` uses a 3rd party API. This API has hourly/daily rate limit.

Sometimes I have spikes in the workload. All pipelines but API pipelines can scale up to handle the workload. But not the API pipeline. It can eventually catch up, but not right away.

Is there a way to throttle down a pub/sub topic/subscription throughput to a specific number of messages per hour/day?

Pretty sure the answer is NO. If so, what are my other options?

Comment: Have you checked out [subscriber flow control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#flow_control)? Using flow control it is possible to control the rate at which the subscriber receives messages.

Comment: Yep, well aware of that. that's not how it works. It's how many messages a pipline processes in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, the answer is no. Cloud Task has that [throttling feature (named rate limit)](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#rate).

One solution design could be:

1. PubSub invokes the next step
2. Processing (Cloud Functions/Cloud Run/Something else) that stack the request in Cloud Task
3. Cloud Task invokes the next step
4. Processing (Cloud Functions/Cloud Run/Something else) that call your 3rd party API

Quite dirty, but you haven't other built-in solution on Google Cloud.

Comment: How about a "relay" VM? Direct all output queues to it for redirects and make it stateful. It'll decide how many messages and at what pace should it send to the respective pipelines.

Comment: I don't like the VM; You have to maintain them, backup them, observe them,... I prefer serverless. But if VM are fine for you, let do it!